# Fabric looks sheer from distance

Tags: modeling

I'm really new to blender and I'm confused as to why the fabric looks sheer when I look at it from far away .
[image]

[image]

Comment: Possibly insufficient depth-resolution, due to your clipping range being too high. See [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/191539/35559), and others.

Comment: thank you it works now !